# Maximum degree of triangle.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\Delta$ denote the maximum degree of a graph,
$$
\Delta = \max_u n_u.
$$

In layman terms, what is this definition saying and what does it mean by maximum and minimum degree?

(This is part of a programming question involving connected graphs)

Comment: What are $u$ and $n_u$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context it's hard to guess exactly, but I think if you have a graph $G$ with vertices $V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$, we can define the *degree* of each vertex as the number of edges in $G$ adjacent to it.

Then, maximum and minimum degree are the max and min of the set of degrees for every vertex.

**UPDATE - EXAMPLES**

- In a cycle on $n$ vertices, both minimal and maximal degree are $2$.
- In a complete graph on $n$ vertices, both minimal and maximal degree are $n-1$.
- In a graph which looks like a square (on $4$ vertices) with one added diagonal, the minimal degree is $2$ (in any one of 2 vertices without the diagonal) and the maximal degree is $3$ (in one of vertices touching the extra diagonal).

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not allowed to give any more information than that. That would make sense though in terms of my problem and desired algorithm! That last example really helped, thanks.